# how can unpack a list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

I have a list of dict which each dict can have a list of dict nested in like:

```
mydictlist = [{'name':'foo'}, {'name':'bar','next-level':[{'name':'next-level-foo'}, {'name':'next-level-bar'}] } ]
```

I am trying to flatten some kind of attribute like name in list comprehension like this:

```
flattened = [ *['{}_{}'.format(iter['name'],next['name']) for next in iter] if 'next-level' in iter else '{}'.format(iter['name']) for iter in mydictlist]
```

to get something like :

```
['foo', 'bar_next-level-foo', 'bar_next-level-bar']
```

but this result in error!. I can do it with for and if without list comprehension (and have done that) but I want to know what is the correct syntax for doing that with list (or tuple unpacking) and list comprehension?

Comment: will be there more next level in the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest one I can do is to provide a "fake" second level when necessary, and ignoring it afterwards:

```
mydictlist = [{'name':'foo'}, {'name':'bar','next-level':[{'name':'next-level-foo'}, {'name':'next-level-bar'}] } ]

flattened = [ '{}_{}'.format(item['name'],next['name']) if next['name'] else item['name'] for item in mydictlist for next in (item['next-level'] if 'next-level' in item else  [{'name':None}]) ]
```

Output:

> ```
> ['foo', 'bar_next-level-foo', 'bar_next-level-bar']
> ```

There do not seem a way for conditionally loop in a list comprehension. So if there are two `for`-s, they will both run, but the "subject" of the second loop can be generated conditionally (originally I did that with a lambda, but apparently a parenthesed expression is enough).

Your attempt had a bug, `for next in iter` should have been `for next in iter['next-level']` (also, `iter()` is a built-in function, so I renamed the thing to `item`).
And if you tried something less ambitious, you would have encountered an explicit error message: ***iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension***.

Comment: this is not my original code, I have a third level and two type of third level so I was trying to simplify things. my original code was more complex than this and was not appropriate for a question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
mydictlist = [{'name':'foo'}, {'name':'bar','next-level':[{'name':'next-level-foo'}, {'name':'next-level-bar'}] } ]

def flatten(currlist, prefix = None, delimiter = "_"):
    l = []
    for x in currlist:
        print (l)
        if "next-level" in x:
            if prefix:
                prefix = delimiter.join([prefix, x["name"]])
            else:
                prefix = x["name"]
            c = flatten(currlist=x["next-level"], prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)
            l.extend(c)
        else:
            if not prefix:
                item = x["name"]
            else:
                item = delimiter.join([prefix, x["name"]])
            l.append(item)
    return l

flatten(currlist=mydictlist)
```

Comment: I have already done it with similar code, but I want to know how to do it with list comprehension

Comment: I don't think list comprehension is suitable in this case. It's syntactic sugar used to avoid writing for loops when the logic is fairly simple but this is not the silver bullet to everything. To be used only when it helps making your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is you want nearly

```
result = [x['name'] if "next-level" not in x else [ j['name'] for j in x['next-level']] for x in mydictlist ]
print(result)
# output: ['foo', ['next-level-foo', 'next-level-bar']]
result2 = []
def flettern_list(lst):
    for s in lst:
        if isinstance(s, str):
            result2.append(s)
        elif isinstance(s, list):
            flettern_list(s)
flettern_list(result)
print(result2) #output: ['foo', 'next-level-foo', 'next-level-bar']
```

Comment: this result in nested list not a flattened list

Comment: thanks. I have finished the job and I am looking for a one-line list comprehension. and it seems its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly generic solution that will recurse in any kind of combination of dict and list. This will return a flat list of name values.

```
def get_leafs_as_list(obj, key):
    l = []
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for v in obj:
            l.extend(get_leafs_as_list(v, key))
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k == key:
                l.append(v)
            else:
                l.extend(get_leafs_as_list(v, key))
    return l

mydictlist = [{'name':'foo'}, {'name':'bar','next-level':[{'name':'next-level-foo'}, {'name':'next-level-bar'}] } ]

print(get_leafs_as_list(mydictlist, 'name'))
```

this will return:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'next-level-foo', 'next-level-bar']
```